# Profile 2 fields not displaying in registration form

Tags: users

I create 2 Profiles with distinct Fields as well as assigned each one a unique role with permissions to Administer Profile2 registration paths, but all I'm getting is the default Username and E-mail fields nothing else (On both of them).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you check to "Show during user account registration" on the profile type.

**Admin > Structure > Profile Types > [Type] > Edit**

[image: Profile type edit form]

Comment: When Editing the Profile Types that option does not appear, instead I am prompted with a check box for the following: "Show on all user account registration forms." 
http://imgur.com/aC9Qaj0

Comment: Jason, thats what you need to enable to attach the profile to the registration page.